# How to make a camera follow a specific particle

Tags: particles, camera, tracking

I have been tasked with having a camera follow a specific piece of paper as it moves through an office environment. The paper is one of many that are flowing along and the shot is from the view of this one piece of paper. I know I can hand animate it, but I was wondering if there is a way to track the camera to a particle and see from it's POV (so to speak).  I would like to attach to the particle and look from it as if the camera were riding on the paper.

Comment: Do you want the camera to track the particle (look at it)? Or look from the particle (attach to it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to manually animate the camera and keep a single particle object (piece of paper) in the field of view. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

- Have one piece of paper not a particle.  This item is special and follows a path. Use the follow path constraint.
- You might consider baking a one particle  .. particle system.  Total 2 particle systems.
- The camera can follow the path as well thus following the paper as well.
- The other pieces of paper remain as particles.